# How to create a concrete function for getting coordinates of a masked image and convert it to tensorflow lite model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-lite

How to create concrete function in tensorflow to get semantic segmentation image and calculate co-ordinates.

We are having current code for the same but not able to concrete function as we wanted to convert in tflite file for mobile application.

```
def predict_new_image(img_path, model):
img = load_img(img_path, grayscale=True)
x_img = img_to_array(img)
x_img = resize(x_img, (128, 128, 1), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)

X = np.zeros((1, 128, 128, 1), dtype=np.float32)
y_img = np.zeros((1, 128, 128, 1), dtype=np.float32)
X[0, ..., 0] = x_img.squeeze() / 255

pred = model.predict(X)
preds_img = (pred > 0.5).astype(np.uint8)

img_arr = preds_img[:,:,0]

# get the coordinates where the pixel isn't white (at a threshold)
black_thres = 1
idx = [(i,j) for i,x in enumerate(img_arr) for j,y in enumerate(x) if img_arr[i,j]==black_thres]
return idx
```